# How does one achieve this layout with CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

The individual elements I have created using CSS and bootstrap standards however to get them to stack like that I do not know where to begin. Is it possible?

Comment: I would recommend first inspecting the HTML/CSS of the page that you got that screenshot from. If there's something in there that you can't reproduce on your own code, you can show us and we have a beginning point. As it stands, this question is very vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code is helpful to you based on the above picture...

Please find the sample also in  [CodePen](http://codepen.io/YaserAliPeedikakkal/pen/mVMPEY)

```css
.icon {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.left-pane {
  height: 300px;
  background:#00b386; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 left-pane">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img src="image.jpg" class="icon">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img src="image.jpg" class="icon">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img src="image.jpg" class="icon">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrdrVd

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x550" alt="test" class="img-responsive">

            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            </div>

         </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>


         </div>
                     <div class="col-md-12">

           <h1>Example headline.</h1>

         </div>
                     <div class="col-md-12">

           <h1>Example headline.</h1>

         </div>

         </div>


 </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to read up some more on the possibilities of the [bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

That layout is achieved by creating two half-width (6 out of 12) columns, and then nesting 3 rows inside the right column. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/edjgdg2s/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row margin-bottom">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 border">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 tall border">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 border">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 border">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 border">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```